# Is this subgroup diagram of $\mathbb{Z}_{90}$ correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

I'm trying to practice drawing 3D subgroup diagrams for certain $\mathbb{Z}_n$ since that seems to be a necessity for some $n$. Specifically, I tried out $\mathbb{Z}_{90}$ and I'm wondering if this is correct? I saw another diagram [here](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SubgroupLatticesOfFiniteCyclicGroups/) that looked more 4-dimensional so I'm not sure if mine is right. Here is the picture I drew:

[[image: My subgroup diagram of <span class=]$\mathbb{Z}_{90}$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt9Ay.jpg)

EDIT: Whoops, I forgot about $\langle 18 \rangle$! I would put that in the bottom left corner that is not filled in. My bad lol!

Comment: For a cyclic group $\Bbb Z_n$, there's exactly one (cyclic) subgroup for each divisor of $n$ (including $1$ and $n$ themselves). Since $90$ has twelve divisors, that's how many subgroups there should be; I think you got them all. Also, the "dimension" of the picture will be the number of distinct primes dividing $n$ (three in this case); see if you can figure out why....

Comment: @GregMartin I knew that the dimension of the picture is the same as the number of the distinct primes dividing $n$. Is this the reason why? Suppose $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\dots p_j^{k_j}$ for primes $p_i$ and positive integers $k_i$. Then each $\langle p_i \rangle$ has its own set of subgroups, so there are $j$ sets of subgroups to worry about. 1/

Comment: Let $P_i$ be the set of subgroups of $\langle p_i \rangle$ for all $1\leq i \leq j$. Then the intersection $P_i\bigcap P_m$ need not be empty for $1\leq i,m \leq j$ since the trivial subgroup $\{0\}$ is contained in every $P_i$. Therefore, each $P_i$ needs its own dimension in the picture to accommodate these nonempty intersections. Is that right? 2/2

Comment: Oops, I should have said the $p_i$ are *distinct*!

Answer (score 3):

Your idea with the parallelogram can be implemented that way. In the picture, the number means the order of the subgroup. If two subgroups are connected by an edge, the higher order subgroup lies higher.
[image]